# Help with the chain rule

Tags: calculus, chain-rule

Let $f: (0,1) \times (0,\infty) \times (0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$, $ f \in C^{1}$. I want to know if the following relationship is true by the chain rule. I don't know how to apply the chain rule, I think.

$$
f_{x}(x,s,t)f_{x,t}(x,s,t) + f_{x}(x,s,t)f_{x,s}(x,s,t) = \dfrac{d}{2dt}|f_{x}(x,s,t)|^{2}
$$
I think that
$$
\dfrac{d}{2dt}|f_{x}(x,s,t)|^{2} = f_{x}(x,s,t)f_{x,t}(x,s,t)
$$

I'm confusing myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second equality is correct, assuming the necessary derivatives exist. The first equality could potentially hold if you plug in $s=t$ or with some funky $t$ dependence. When differentiating w.r.t. $t$ we can mostly assume that all other variables are constant (if you know they're not it should be explicitly stated).

PS: $\frac{d}{dt}$ isn't really a fraction, so you shouldn't write $2$ in the denominator.

Comment: $$
\dfrac{1}{2}\bigg(\dfrac{d}{dt}|f_{x}(x,s,t)|^{2} + \dfrac{d}{ds}|f_{x}(x,s,t)|^{2} \bigg)= f_{x}(x,s,t)f_{x,t}(x,s,t) +  f_{x}(x,s,t)f_{x,s}(x,s,t)
$$

Comment: Is it ok???? Thank you

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome :)